# How to find numbers of valid subString using O(n) time complexity algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, substring, time-complexity, complexity-theory

so I'm in need of a java method that receives a String type variable, a char type variable and an int type variable:

```
public static int subStrMaxC(String s, char c, int k)
```

So this method's idea is to check how many subStrings are in the String s that start and end with the character c and has maximum k c characters inside them.
while using time complexity of O(n) while `n == s.length()`
adding the API documentation below:

```
/**
     * Checks how many Sub-Strings are within a given String that starts and ends with a given character and also has that character inside the Sub-String maximum a given amount of times.
     * @param s the String to check for the Sub-String within.
     * @param c the character to check the Sub-String according to.
     * @param k the amount of time that the given character has to be within every Sub-String.
     * @return the number of the valid Sub-Strings.
     * @timeComplexity O(n) n - the String's (s) length.
     * @SpaceComplexity O(1)
     */
```

for example:
    subStrMaxC("abcabcabc", 'c', 1);
should return 3 because the valid subString are:
"cabc" , "cabc" , "cabcabc"

here is my code but it doesn't return the right answers:

```
public static int subStrMaxC(String s, char c, int k) {
    int count = 0, toReturn = 0;
    for(int index = 0; index < s.length(); index++) {
        if(s.charAt(index) == c)
            count++;
    }

    while(k >= 0) {
        if(k == 0)
            return toReturn;
        else if(k % 2 == 0) {
            toReturn += count - (k + 1) - toReturn;
            k--;
        }
        else {
            toReturn += count / 2 - toReturn;
            k--;
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Would love to get some help! Thanks !

Comment: What values does it return, for the same inputs?

Comment: I didn't understand, what inputs are the same?

Comment: You say your code produces doesn't produce the right answers. What answers does it produce?

Comment: You want to find the number of pairs of char c in s wich are at most k positions away from each other. hint: sliding window

Comment: "You want to find the number of pairs of char c in s wich are at most k positions away from each other. hint: sliding window" i know but the question is how can i do it in time complexity of O(n), i can use O(n^2) and do what you just said with two for loops

Comment: Why should `subStrMaxc("fsdsdcrtjjjysf", f, 13)` give 6? I suppose the f should be quoted to make it a character constant.

Comment: you're right i used the wrong string it is applied for the string "fsdfsdfxxdsfds"

Comment: "You say your code produces doesn't produce the right answers. What answers does it produce? –" for subStrMaxc("fsdfsdfxxdsfds", f, 13) my method returns 2 instead of 6, for an instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to make few observations to solve this problem:

Assume that we have the longest valid substring that end at index `ith`, which contains `x` character `c`, with `x <= k`, so, in total, it contains `x + 2` character `c`. We can say that, any substring that end at this index `ith` and start at any of the first `x+1` character is a valid substring.

So, for each character `c` in the string, we just need to find the number of character `c` (denotes as `count`) that stand before it, if it greater than `k + 1`, just add `k + 1` to the result, otherwise, just add `count`.

So here is the pseudo code:

```
int result = 0;
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    if(s.charAt(i) == c){
       result += Integer.min(k + 1, count);
       count++;
    } 
}
```

Time complexity: O(n)

Working demo: https://ideone.com/aUpxk5